# The law of large numbers

Tags: probability, applications, law-of-large-numbers

I'm currently writing a dissertation on the law of large numbers. The 4th chapter is on the real-life applications of the laws themselves. I have found applications for the laws in general but would like to find applications of the weak law and strong law individually. Any applications of either the weak or the strong would be amazing!